# Insert array into database in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to insert an array using the following code.

```
$notif = new Notification();
$notif->recipient_id = auth()->user()->id;
$notif->sender_id = auth()->user()->id;
$notif->unread = true;
$notif->content = "Top up voucher {$voucher->id} | $amount dalam proses";
$notif->type = 'topup';
$link[] =  [
        'route_name' => 'topup.detail-confirm',
        'param' => ['param_name' => 'id', 'param_value' => $transaction->id]
];
$notif->link = $link;
$notif->save();
```

I get the following error.

> array to string conversion

Comment: which line? What exact error?

Comment: $notif->link = $link;

Comment: I don't think MySQL support `array` data type. So, you'll need to convert your array to `JSON string` before storing it in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to say without a little more detail, but I think the most likely culprit is exactly what the error is telling you.  You are trying to save this array:

```
$link[] =  [
        'route_name' => 'topup.detail-confirm',
        'param' => ['param_name' => 'id', 'param_value' => $transaction->id]
];
```

Into a non-array field.

You can do several things, but an easy quick test to fix might be to encode it as a string like so:

```
$notif->link = json_encode($link);
```

If that saves, then when you pull it out, remember `json_decode` it.

You can play with different methods to stringify (and/or DB column types), but the above may help you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the string to array, but not using `json_encode`, forget about `json_encode` and `json_decode` unless you are working with an external API...

To cast it, you just have to first read the [**documentation**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) as it has a section dedicated to casting any type of value...

So, your model would have to be like this:

```php
class Notification extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'link' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

So next time you want to read the field `link`, you just do `$this->link` and think it will return an `array`, no need for you to do anything (but behind scenes, it is using `json_decode`).

And when you want to save the value, you just do:

```php
$array = [
    'index1' => 123,
    'index2' => [
        'sub_index1' => true,
        'sub_index2' => '2020-08-27'
    ]
];

// Or whatever array you want to save

$model->link = $array;
```